# error illegal start of expression 11111

Tags: java

Here is the code that keeps saying illegal start of expression:

```
 public static conversionRate= 4.546;
```

Here is the full code:

```
/**
 * Write a description of class VolumeConversion here.
 * 

 * @author (Aneeqa Rustam) 
 * @version (07/08/2014)
 */

public class VolumeConversion
{

 // instance variables - replace the example below with your own


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class VolumeConversion
     */
    public VolumeConversion()
    {
     public static conversionRate= 4.546;

     znaslcmlkmlskm(String[]args)

      //Declare the variable and constants 

      double litres= 0;
      double gallon= 14;

      //Perform the conversion calculation 

      litres= gallon* conversionRate;

      //This is the output result that is going to be shown to the user

     System.out.println("The number of litres in "+gallons+ "gallons is" +litres);

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a type for the variable. For example:

```
public static float conversionRate = 4.546f;
```

You also want to place that outside of the constructor, as a class level variable.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `conversionRate` doesn't have a type in its declaration.

Possible solutions:

```
public static float conversionRate = 4.546f;
public static double conversionRate = 4.546;
```

Besides that you try to declare this variable in the constructor (a "method"). That does not work. It has to be declared within `class` and not in methods.

Comment: Note: you do not need the 'd' for double as java interprets number literals with decimal points as double.

Answer (score 1):

Type is missing in the variable declaration

Answer (score 0):

Well, this one is quite obvious - you haven't defined the datatype for your `conversionRate` variable. What you'd probably want to use here is the [double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) datatype, but I'd also suggest looking into [BigDecimals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for further reference.

Code sample:

```
public static double CONVERSION_RATE = 4.546;
```

I would personally recommend against using the [float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) datatype (as @MrTux recommended) in real life projects, as it tends to make your code clumsier (unnecessary casting & parsing) and has the obvious limitation of a restricted value range. The performance penalty that results from the use of `double` in place of `float`, however, is miniscule in most cases.